# How to retrieve all the values starting with A to M in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to retrieve all the values that are starting with A to M in hive. I tried using LIKE operator in SQL, but not able to get it done on HIVE. This is the below statement that I am trying

```
SELECT * FROM cust WHERE first_name LIKE '[A-M]%';
```

Can some one provide me the solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You are using SQL Server conventions for Hive, which I don't think it supports.  Here are two easy ways that don't involve regular expressions:

```
WHERE substring(first_name, 1, 1) between 'A' and 'M'
WHERE first_name >= 'A' and first_name < 'N'
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using `rlike`

```
WHERE first_name RLIKE '^[A-M]'
```